# smb share takes forever to connect to from Mac OS X 10.7-8

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, server-message-block

Ive got a dozen users and half of them take forever to connect to the smb share coming from a windows server 2008 r 2 standard server. Some users instantly connect with no issue.

These Mac OS X workstations have been clean formatted to see if it was a OS issue but still some take forever to connect.

I am wondering if there is something on the server side that can assist.

Comment: how are the user's resolving the server name? via DNS or via NETBIOS?

Answer (score 0):

The Lord's ways are mysterious, but the vagaries of SMB in a mixed OS environment even more so....

So I don't claim to have the full answer, but there are a couple of things you can try:

- If possible have ipv6 enabled on both OSX and Windows. Even if it is with just automatically generated addresses. A number of name-resolution related things work better that way between Windows and OSX.
- Install the Bonjour printing service for Windows on the W2K8 machine. Even if you don't have print-queues on the server it makes the server announce it presence to the Macs which should help.
- If all else fails: Try to accesss the SMB share by smb://ip-address/share and/or by smb://servername.local/share
- For some obscure reason that I never managed to figure out sometimes it helps to access the share using cifs:// in stead of smb://. They should amount to the same thing, but somehow that is not always true.